# Support ANSI terminal color escape sequences in XML?

Tags: eclipse, text, colors, centos, format

I am using "termcolor" and "colored" for printing some colored words in my test script.

```
>>> from termcolor import colored
>>> result = colored("pass", "red")
>>> print result
pass ----> ("appears in red")
>>> result = '\033[1m' + result  + '\033[0m'
>>> print result
pass ------> ("appears in red and bold")
```

The above works fine on Mac and CentOS but fails to print it in red or bold in eclipse (on CentOS). It prints something like this "?[32mPASS?[0m" -- which does not help much..

I want to add that, the above text is seen on an XML file opened in eclipse. The encoding format probably has a role to play here. Right now I see "UTF-8" in the XML as encoding format.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that unlike most terminals, the default Eclipse console does not know how to deal with the [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) that provide the color information.

There is however a plugin called **ANSI Escape in Console** available from the Eclipse marketplace that augments the standard Eclipse console to be able to deal with these ANSI color escape sequences:

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console#.U978fXV515Q

The plugin author's blog provides some more information:

http://mihai-nita.net/2013/06/03/eclipse-plugin-ansi-in-console/

Comment: Nope - tried it Robby, did not work. I still have the following with no color or no bold font - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><system-out><![
 ?[32mPASS?[0m
 ?[32mPASS?[0m

]]></system-out></testcase></testsuite>

Comment: Hold on, what's this about the XML file you added to your question? Are you trying to view these colors in the Eclipse console, or in an Eclipse XML editor?

Comment: Eclipse generates an XML file -- so I thought it would be good to add that information.

Comment: So you want an Eclipse XML editor with support for ANSI terminal color escape sequences. I'm afraid there's no plugin for that.

Comment: Oh.. Ok So -- is there anything else I could do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Short of writing your own Eclipse plugin? Not a whole lot in my opinion.